# Python variable in bytes

Tags: python, computer-science

By theory please correct me if I am wrong, it says that an `int` can take upto max 4 bits in case of number `9`.

I haven't coded it low level languages but I assume that the datatype int in c and python shouldn't be different.

I want to know what is the reason that in Python an int is taking **24 bytes**

Also if someone can explain how a bit/byte is calculated for a character.

Thanks

```
>>> var = 1
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.getsizeof(var)
24
>>> var = 'Raheel'
>>> print sys.getsizeof(var)
43
>>> var = 2
>>> print sys.getsizeof(var)
24
>>> var = 'R'
>>> print sys.getsizeof(var)
38
>>>
```

Comment: It depends on the implementation. In CPython, all objects are actually [C structs](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h) and contains much more stuff than just a single value.

Comment: What is "it" as in "it says that an `int`"... as it is not correct. Where are you getting this info? You should read this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: I was watching CS50 course on edx. I cannot provide a link here as it is not public page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocation unit cannot be smaller that 1 byte. For a 1-bit variable (a Boolean value) you have to allocate at least 8 bits, 7 of them unused.

A modern CPU operates on 64 bits (8 bytes), some on 32 bits = 4 bytes; 16-bit embedded controllers are common, 8-bit controllers are already rare. RAM also works more efficiently with larger widths, and normally expects alignment on 4-byte border for efficient fetches. This is why a 1-bit value can even take up 4 bytes in memory.

A Python integer is an object. Yes, you can invoke methods right on an integer constant: `(1).__add__(2)` or `(100).bit_length()`. This means that the actual integer value is stored along with a lot of other information.

Python integers try to adapt to the size of data, more so in Python 3 were an integer of *any* length is an object of the same type, just allocating enough bytes to store the value.

You can indeed *pack* values of small magnitude to more efficiently use the bits available. This is common is storage formats, especially where bandwidth is important. E.g. a GPU can work with textures packed in various ways, both as integers and (short) floats. Most modern CPUs have "vector instructions" to work with several independent 16-bit and 8-bit integers packed into 32- or 64-bit registers.